# How to find all websites matching the pattern website.edu/~<some_string>?

Tags: search, website, domain, search-engines, parsing

It's common among university lecturers to have their own web pages on the university domain and share resources there. If the name of a professor is John Smith then he his website may be harvard.edu/~jsmith.

I want to find all such pages on a given website i.e. all the pages that look like website.edu/~[some_string] - note the tilde. The reason is I'm looking for some resources that I know are there but don't know the name of the person that shared it.

I already tried:

1. Google search. Not very effective as once I accidentally came across something I was looking for but it was via hyperlink on another webpage on this domain and Google didn't return it when I was searching for it before that - maybe it's not indexed at all, not sure about that.
2. Using Google search modifier site:"websitename.edu/~" but it didn't work - I expected this since this modifier only accepts a dot as a separator.

Theoretically, I suppose it would be possible to try to access all possible website of the form website.edu/~[string] where [string] is some sequence of characters and try all the possibilities up to some character limit, and save those links that don't return an error message. But there must be some easier way.

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Google, this is actually pretty easy:

```
site:http://www.cameron.edu/~
```

... for instance lists various professor pages.  *(In response to the edited question>>>)  Note:  there is no quotes ("") in the search string.*

```
8mm site:http://www.cameron.edu/~
```

... shows professors interested in 8mm film, in this case, Dr. Matt Jenkins

Have fun!  8-)

Comment: I thought it was the website name should be in " " - tried this as you suggested and it worked, thanks. :)